# Homomorphism from complex numbers with addition to the non zero complex numbers with multiplication injective? Surjective?

Tags: group-theory, complex-numbers

Homomorphism from complex numbers with addition to the non zero complex numbers with multiplication injective? Surjective?

I have been given the map $\phi:\mathbb{C}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$ by $\phi:z \mapsto e^z$.

I have shown the map is not injective.

I'm not sure about surjectivity though?

How do I prove it is surjective (or not)?

Comment: Why $e^z =1 \iff z= 0$?  That's the definition of a trivial kernel, but you haven't shown it.  (in fact it's not true.)

Comment: What about $e^{2\pi i}$?

Comment: Oh okay my bad. So $e^{2\pi i}=1$ therefore the kernel is not trivial and so the map cannot be injective. What about surjectivity?

Comment: If it's not injective it's not an isomorphism.  You don't also need to find out whether or not it is surjective (unless you are specifically asked to, or you are just curious.)

Comment: Note that the fact that this specific map is not an isomorphism does not prove that the sets are not isomorphic.  You would need to show that there is no possible isomorphism.

Comment: Yeah I understand that but I am also being asked specifically about surjectivity. But out of interest is it surjective? I updated the title as it was misleading.

Comment: Ah I see.  Well, I'd suggest using Euler's formula and thinking geometrically...

Comment: $z \mapsto \log z$ is a (continuous) group isomorphism $(\mathbb{C}^*,\times) \to (\mathbb{C}/2i\pi \mathbb{Z},+)$

Comment: Can you be more explicit I cannot understand how to see if $\phi$ is surjective. We have $e^z=e^{x+iy}=e^xe^{iy}=e^x(\cos(y)+i\sin (y))$ but I do not see how to show everything is mapped to (or find something that isn't)?

Comment: Decompose $z \in \mathbb{C}^*$ as $|z| \frac{z}{|z|}$ where $|z| > 0$ and $\frac{z}{|z|}$ is on the unit circle, and show the surjectivity for those two components separately.

Comment: Sorry I still do not understand thanks for the effort though.